# How to add Authorization header for API requests globally in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, api

When I send the header in such code the Api receives the token correctly :

`$response = Http::withHeaders(["Authorization" => "Bearer token"])->get('httpa://example.com/api/v1/user');`

I'm trying to do this globally so I don't have to write withHeaders all the time on every request.
I created a middleware with this code and connected it to app/Http/kernel.php

````
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class BearerAuthMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $request->headers->set('Authorization', 'Bearer token');
        return $next($request);
    
    }
} ```

but not work. The api does not receive this header
````

Answer (score 2):

You can create a macro as mentioned in the document.Define the macro within the `boot` method of your application's `App\Providers\AppServiceProvider` class:

```
public function boot()
{
        Http::macro('github', function () {
            return Http::withToken('token')->baseUrl('https://github.com');
        });
}
```

and use like below

```
$response = Http::github()->get('/');
```

Ref :

[Bearer Tokens](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/http-client#bearer-tokens)

[Macros](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/http-client#macros)

Answer (score 1):

the token should be a variable like so `$response = Http::withHeaders(["Authorization" => "Bearer $token"])->get('httpa://example.com/api/v1/user');`

Comment: I know, this is only example. Doesn't change the fact that if there is a "token" string, it should return a "token" string, and it wasn't. After using the macro it works

Comment: Theb the answer with the `macro` solution should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

Okay, but here you also have to enter a macro for each request. No way to make the header globally appended to every request but under certain conditions? For example, that `$request->is('api/*')` and there is a token in the session?